# Webrtc mediastream don't have SDP/TLS and don't have DTLS

Tags: webrtc, dtls

I have a app can take call via WebRTC in iOS, this working normal when call with browser, but when call with android app I can't set remote sdp with error: Called with SDP without DTLS fingerprint. After searching I found that the sdp send from android don't have DTLS param: a=setup..., a=fingerprint.... and the stream media only has RTP/AVPF like below. Can you help me to fix this problem.
Thanks!
note: Android call with android is normal.

```
m=video 9 RTP/AVPF 96 97 98 99 100 101 127 123 125
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally I found the answer, because in android app has a setting to disable encryption in peer connection Factory option cause this bug, so I change disableEncryption to false and every thing work fine.

```
.setOptions(PeerConnectionFactory.Options().apply {
                disableEncryption = false
                disableNetworkMonitor = true
            })
```